# Cloudflare not forwarding ETag header?

Tags: http, cloudflare, etag

I have a site (e.g. http://example.com) that uses Cloudflare. Nothing special, no weird page rules, no weird settings, free plan.

When I go to http://example.com, I get this response for the GET http://example.com request:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
CF-RAY:2b8d0490837f2828-SJC
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 26 Jun 2016 01:52:05 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:cloudflare-nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Notice that the response has no ETag header, even though it's enabled on my origin server.

When I go to the origin server directly, e.g. GET http://01.23.456.789/, I get this response:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sun, 26 Jun 2016 01:56:53 GMT
ETag:W/"4cf8-1558a5557a0"
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Does anyone know why Cloudflare wouldn't be forwarding the ETag header? How can I make Cloudflare forward the ETag? Cloudflare isn't caching the GET http://example.com request by default since it's an HTML page.

Comment: That looks like an interesting issue, can you email supportATcloudflareDOTcom so we can assist you with this issue?

Comment: I have lost an entire day due to this strange Cloudflare behavior...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I spoke with a Cloudflare Tech Support Engineer and he helped fixed my issue. For anyone in the future who might have this same problem, here's what fixed it:

I had Email Obfuscation enabled for the URL in question (that was getting its ETag header removed). According to https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218505467-Does-CloudFlare-support-ETag-headers-,

```
Email Obfuscation will need to be disabled, otherwise the ETag headers
will be removed from the response. Email Obfuscation modifies the code
significantly enough it cannot be considered semantically equivalent.
```

Disabling Email Obfuscation still didn't fix it, though. Turns out I had an app enabled that would modify the HTML, so the ETag had to be invalidated. In the end, setting a Page Rule with Disable Security, Disable Apps, Disable Performance for that URL did the trick.

Comment: In my case disabling Email Obfuscation and Automatic HTTPS Rewrites, as described in the docs, was enough

Comment: You need to disable Auto Minify as well, in Speed - Optimization - Auto Minify

Answer (score 1):

disable Email Obfuscation and Automatic HTTPS Rewrites, as documented at [Cloudflare support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218505467-Using-ETag-Headers-with-Cloudflare):

> When using weak ETag headers, **disable Email Obfuscation and Automatic
> HTTPS Rewrites** to ensure Cloudflare doesn't remove the ETag headers
> set by your origin web server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered the same situation.
Disabling Email Obfuscation and Automatic HTTPS Rewrites is not enough for me, because I have installed 'A Better Browser' app (https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/a-better-browser) on Cloudflare Apps.
After uninstalling that app, the `Etag` shows up.